# How do I divide in [ for (); ]

Tags: java

I have a code that will check if the number is prime.

I want the code to take the user input and divide it from 1 to the number they input.

If the result has 3 or more results , Return is as false. ( Prime numbers can only be divided by 1 and itself. )

Here is my code:

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class PrimeNumber {

    public static void main (String args[] ) {

     int num ;
     System.out.print("Enter a number : ");
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     num = sc.nextInt();

     for ( int n=1; num / n; n<num; n++ ){
        System.out.print(num + " is an integer. ");
     }
  }
}
```

At `num / n;`, It does not work. I want `num` to start dividing from 1 and make its way up to itself and stop.

Why can't I divide inside the for part. I understand the logic, But I cant get that part to work.

Comment: You should really include the compiler error in your question. Also explain what results you expect, because I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Pretty sure your code does not compile. The for expressions are wrong.

Comment: You are not using the `for` statement correctly. See [The `for` Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials for a detailed explanation of how to use it.

Comment: for loops work like this 
for -do this until done-(Beginning at -where you start-; finish as -where you end-; Do each-do this each iteration-)

Answer (score 1):

The `for` second argument must be a boolean condition: `for( ; boolean condition; ) {}`

The second argument must be a boolean condition, not any expression.
On your original post, if you just need it to compile, adjust it to `num/n>0`.
On the current version, to compile, you just need to remove it from the `for` loop.

But if you need to know if a number is prime, check it: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-determine-a-prime-number-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're trying to do is

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PrimeNumber {
public static void main (String args[] ) {
    int num ;
    System.out.print("Enter a number : ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    num = sc.nextInt();
    for ( int n=1; n<num; n++ ){
        if (num % n == 0)
            System.out.print(n + " is an factor. ");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand what you want to do but I guess is much better if you try to use another conditional.

```
If(n<num)
{
  System.out.println(num + " is an integer. ");
}
else
{
System.out.println("false");
}
```